# Use react-three-fiber's instance mesh to render a gltf model multiple times

Tags: reactjs, typescript, three.js, 3d, react-three-fiber

I have a 3d gltf model which I want to render multiple times probably 100K but this cause performance lag because of the multiple draw calls. How can I use instance mesh to do this in a single draw call while also being able to send a color prop to each rendered model.

I am using the below code.

```
# Model.tsx

import * as THREE from 'three'
import { useGLTF } from '@react-three/drei'
import { GroupProps } from '@react-three/fiber'
import { GLTF } from 'three-stdlib'

type GLTFResult = GLTF & {
  nodes: {
    Cylinder: THREE.Mesh
    Cylinder_1: THREE.Mesh
    Cylinder_2: THREE.Mesh
  }
  materials: {
    Floor: THREE.MeshStandardMaterial
    Glass: THREE.MeshPhysicalMaterial
    Metal: THREE.MeshStandardMaterial
  }
}

export type Props = {
  color: string
  windowsTint: string
}

const Model = ({ color, windowsTint, ...props }: GroupProps & Props) => {
  const { nodes, materials } = useGLTF('./3d/room.gltf') as GLTFResult
  return (
    <group {...props} dispose={null}>
      <mesh castShadow receiveShadow geometry={nodes.Cylinder.geometry}>
        <meshStandardMaterial
          color={color}
          roughness={0.6}
          metalness={0.3}
          side={THREE.DoubleSide}
        />
      </mesh>
      <mesh castShadow receiveShadow geometry={nodes.Cylinder_1.geometry}>
        <meshPhongMaterial color={windowsTint} transparent opacity={0.7} side={THREE.DoubleSide} />
      </mesh>
      <mesh
        castShadow
        receiveShadow
        geometry={nodes.Cylinder_2.geometry}
        material={materials.Metal}
      >
        <meshStandardMaterial metalness={0.8} roughness={0.4} color='#888888' />
      </mesh>
    </group>
  )
}

useGLTF.preload('./3d/room.gltf')
export default Model
```

And this is how i am currently rendering 1000 instances

```
#App.tsx

const rooms = [
    ...
    {color: '#f7f7f7', windowTint: 0.9}
]
....

            {rooms.map((room, idx) => {
                return (
                  <Model
                    position={[0, idx * 2, 0]}
                    rotation={[0, Math.PI * 0.08 * idx, 0]}
                    key={`_RL${idx}`}
                    color={room.color}
                    windowsTint={room.windowTint}
                  />
                )
              })}

....
```

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure that all transformations like position or rotation are applied to the geometry. Groups or Mesh cannot have such transformations.

Second, replace all mesh with InstancedMesh and add the same tranformations to each InstancedMesh. To make it easier, you can group them together, for example, with such a class

```js
import { Color, InstancedMesh, Matrix4 } from 'three';

export class InstancedMeshGroup {
    children: InstancedMesh<any, any>[] = [];

    add(...object: InstancedMesh<any, any>[]): this {
        this.children.push(...object);
        return this;
    }

    setMatrixAt(index: number, matrix: Matrix4) {
        this.children.forEach((child) => child.setMatrixAt(index, matrix));
    }

    setColorAt(index: number, color: Color) {
        this.children.forEach((child) => child.setColorAt(index, color));
    }

    instanceMatrixNeedsUpdate() {
        this.children.forEach((child) => (child.instanceMatrix.needsUpdate = true));
    }

    instanceColorNeedsUpdate() {
        this.children.forEach((child) => {
            if (child.instanceColor) {
                child.instanceColor.needsUpdate = true;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

To make this kind of operation easier I created a tool to export models as a group of InstancedMesh. You can test it if you still have a problem

https://webgl-opti.web.app/app

My application also helps to optimize the model before export as code